# Using Python to remove the first column of a file while removing a header section

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to write a program to remove the first 15 lines of text and and also the first column of a space delimited file, but so far I have not been successful, does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

The input file looks like this

`(Version 6f format configuration file)
Metadata title:     gamma_glycine_30C
Number of moves generated:           1
Number of moves tried:               0
Number of moves accepted:            0
Number of prior configuration saves: 0
Number of atoms:                     30000
Number density (Ang^-3):                 0.000000
Supercell dimensions:                10  10  10
Cell (Ang/deg):    70.300823   70.300822   54.806050   90.000000   90.000000  120.000001
Lattice vectors (Ang):
   60.882298  -35.150412    0.000000
    0.000000   70.300822    0.000000
    0.000000    0.000000   54.806050
Atoms:
     1   C     0.000124    0.039337    0.089331
     2   C     0.060663    0.060787    0.022665
     3   C     0.039213    0.099876    0.055998
     4   C     0.002607    0.042231    0.062178
     5   C     0.057769    0.060376    0.095512`

The code as it stands looks like this:

```
# This line allows the user to input the particular filename
filename = input( "Filename (excluding .rmc6f):")
molecules = int(input( "No. of molecules in rmc6f :"))
atoms = int(input( "No. of atoms in rmc6f :"))

#These lines create the .xyz file heading that we will append to later
xyz = open(filename+'.xyz' , 'w')
xyz.write( str(atoms) + '\n' )
xyz.write( str(filename) + '\n' )

#these lines create a stripped down version of the .rmc6f file with only the important columns
import csv
import re
from itertools import islice

row_split = re.compile('\s*\*\s*')

with open(filename+'.rmc6f', 'r') as infile, open(filename+'.intermediate', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    #rdr= csv.reader(filename+'.rmc6f', delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')

    next(islice(infile, 15, 15), None) # skip the first 15 lines in the input file

    for r in infile:
        writer.writerow((r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]))
```

at the moment the output is just the .xyz file headings str(atoms) and str(filename) with no coordinates, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: That `islice` looks a bit confusing... `for r in islice(infile, 15, None)` makes a bit more sense to ignore the first 15 lines...

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is a lot cleaner looking, I think the problem is probably the re.compile section at the moment. I can't say I fully understand re.compile, so it's likely that I'm wrong there